# Generating a private key & certificate request on an iOS device

Tags: ios, ssl

NOTE: This question is NOT related to the keys and certificates used for iOS development/provisioning.

I would like to use TLS client certificates for authentication of iOS devices running my app. In order to achieve this securely, it would be ideal if the device generated its private key itself and requested a certificate from our in-house CA.

I can't find an API in the docs for doing this, but I can see that iOS supports TLS client certificate authentication, so it seems logical that it would be possible. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: this answer is not accepted by you. did you found anything useful on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is objective-c wrapper of Open SSL available. Which can be some help to you. https://github.com/aidansteele/SSCrypto.

You can also use mycrypto( https://bitbucket.org/snej/mycrypto/wiki/Home ) a high level objective-c wrapper for many cryptographic tasks.